# Same ciphertext for same text

Tags: amazon-kms

Is it possible to set up `AWS KMS` in a way so that it would generate same **ciphertext** for the same **text** (e.g. `alpha`) each time?

And if not, what others cryptographic methods should I use? (it would be great if they have libs for `node.js` as well)

Comment: No, it's not possible and having same ciphertext for same plaintext and it's by design. Curious why you'd want same ciphertext for same plaintext though as it increases the possibility of different type of attacks. Might want to have a look at this discussion https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/26249/why-are-rsa-ciphertexts-different-for-the-same-plaintext .

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The reason is that in my product I have to do a lot of various queries on encrypted data (insert or update duplicates, filtering etc.) and the way I want to do it is by encrypting the input data (from user let's say), and using it in my SQL queries. That way I am able to use SQL functionality for filtering etc. instead of doing it all in-memory using for-loops and all that stuff which would take much more time and especially performance.